# Creating a dynamic bar chart in Planet Press Connect and need to add labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working in Planet Press Connect. I have created a dynamic bar chart and now I need to add labels to the data. Can anyone help me. I am a beginner in java script so not sure what to do. Below is the code I have. this creates what I need except the labels.

```
if (results.length) {
// The data-chartdata attribute only holds the key value pairs of the data
var chartData = [];

function addValueToSeries(labelField, valueField) {
  var temp = {};
  temp['value_label'] = record.fields[labelField];
  // Number of series is dynamic, add a value to each series
  for (var i = 0; i < record.tables['Age'].length; i++) {
      temp['values_' + (i+1)] = record.tables['Age'][i].fields[valueField];
  }
  chartData.push(temp);
  }

  addValueToSeries('pls_Age2', 'pls_ageAvg');

  results.attr('data-chartData', JSON.stringify(chartData));

  // Connect the series to the values
  var series = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < record.tables['Age'].length; i++) {
  series[i] = { 'title' : record.tables['Age'][i].fields['pls_ageAvg'],
                'valueField' : 'values_' + (i+1) };
  }

  var graphsData = { 'categoryField' : 'value_label', 'graphs' : series };
  results.attr('data-graphsdata', JSON.stringify(graphsData));
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any indication of what library you're using to produce your barchart, thus it's a little hard to determine how to add labels. Can you give more information on how you're using that data?

Comment: Planet Press Connect makes use of the amCharts library (v3).

Comment: I believe the issue is that there is very little you can do to customize it. In fact, already going into custom scripting such as you did is unfortunately beyond the scope of support. Perhaps the best way to deal with this would be to use a 3rd party library instead of the built-in amCharts version that Connect uses - not because the lib itself is limited but because the integration into Connect prevents a lot of customizations you could open yourself to by using your own. There are plenty of open and free libraries you could use.